# How do I enable MSAA in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi guys I am having a problem with MSAA in Unity. How do I enable MSAA in the quality settings of my project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to:
**Edit > Project Settings.**
Select your quality category.
**Rendering > Anti Aliasing.** Select the appropriate option.
Select your **Camera > Allow MSAA**.
Done.

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, it seems the initial answer doesn't apply to Unity 2019. Following a little research, it appears to me that the only way to get MSAA is probably through the **High Definition Render Pipeline**.

Please see how to *[create an HDRP Asset](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ScriptableRenderPipeline/wiki/HDRP-Asset)*. Also, see *[Enabling MSAA in HDRP Asset](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ScriptableRenderPipeline/wiki/MSAA).*

Comment: @webchatowner Note that MSAA isn't very good in Unity and has a bad habit of screwing up other things. Like making post processing effects render upside down. Or introducing black line artifacts around model edges.

Comment: While @bolkay's answer is appreciated, for Unity 2019.1.3f, it's out of date. The options have changed around, apparently.

Comment: @ErikHermansen I have edited my answer following a little research.